# Systemd Service status remains running even after ExecStart process not present in centos 7.3

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, centos7

I have created a systemd service like way any interruption triggered to running process then it has to restart itself. but service shows its status as running (Used `systemctl status x.service`) even after process is exited (which is mentioned in `exec_start`).
Below is my service script

{

```
[Unit]
Description=xserverd
After=syslog.target rsyslog-x.service systemd-modules-load.service
Requires=rsyslog-x.service systemd-modules-load.service
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/bin/xserver
Restart=always
RestartSec=2s
RemainAfterExit=no
RestartPreventExitStatus=SIGINT
KillMode=process
TimeoutSec=300s
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

}

`/opt/bin/xserver` is a C executable which 777 permission. Added signal handler for SIGINT and SIGSEGV. SIGINT is to say proper exit from user. SIGSEGV to log backtrace to our custom log file. Whenever process receives these signals it will exit with
{
`exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`
}

Answer (score 1):

For `Type=forking`, systemd assume the child or child of child of the start command is the daemon process.

Change it to `simple` if your daemon does not go this way.